# Quarto: Cannot render any quarto document in R/Rstudio, OS ERROR O3

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio, quarto

I am not able to render any quarto documents from R/Rstudio. Every time I click “Render” on Rstudio or use the console with quarto_render(“path_to_qmd_file”), I get the following os error 3. This only happens with quarto documents but does not happen with rmarkdown documents.

```
ERROR: Error executing '\\XXXXXXXXXX.org\\xxxx\\R\\R-4.1.3\\bin\\Rscript': The system cannot find the path specified. (os error 3)
```

Unable to locate an installed version of R.
Install R from https://cloud.r-project.org/

I only have R. 4.3.0 version on my C drive, and I can’t find any [PATH in my environmental variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYqXf.png) that specify another version of R to execute. [My quarto check is okay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ww5O3.png)

While my quarto documents are in a shared documents, I have tried in my C drive and got the same error. I have tried different versions of R/Rstudio and still failed.